# back button react native web view

Tags: react-native

i asked this question many times but i cant get answer . 
i am really beginner and need some help with that , and kindly i need it be as a button inside the webview
I am creating app with web view that have

app.js

```js
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import TabScreen from './src/screens/tabscreen'
export default function App() {
  return (
    <TabScreen  />
  );
  }
```

Tabscreen.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Tab, Tabs, TabHeading, Icon, Text,Title,Button,Body,Left,Right } from 'native-base';
import Tab1 from './tabs/tab1';
import Tab2 from './tabs/tab2';
import Tab3 from './tabs/tab3';
import Tab4 from './tabs/tab4';
export default class TabsAdvancedExample extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        
      <Container>
           
        <Header>
        


        </Header>
        
        <Tabs>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="cart" /><Text>السوق</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab1 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="paper" /><Text>تصنيفات</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab2 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="home" /><Text>مدونه</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab3 />
          </Tab>
          <Tab heading={ <TabHeading><Icon name="add" /><Text>اضف منتجاتك</Text></TabHeading>}>
            <Tab4 />
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Tab1.js    ( This is where the Web View Exist )

```js
import React from "react";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
export default function App() {
  return (
    <WebView source={{ uri: "http://catalogmasr.com" }} />
  );
  
  }
```

Comment: What do you need? A back button inside the WebView?

Comment: @AndreiOlar  
yes please how to add back button inside webview ?

Comment: You could use https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onmessage OnMessage. When user click the button in the webview, you post a message (window.postMessage) and in react-native manually trigger the route change

Comment: It is important to differentiate between a back button da navigates back to the previous view in the app and a back button that navigates to the previous page within the webView. I don't know which of the two you need, but here is a guide for one of the cases: https://blog.defining.tech/adding-a-back-button-for-react-native-webview-4a6fa9cd0b0

Comment: thanks man i reached the answer @AndreiOlar

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can add back button in the bottom of the webview. Hope this can help :)

```
 import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class WebViewScreen extends React.Component {

  buttonOnPress = () => {
    console.warn('button Pressed')
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.WEBVIEW_REF = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }}
          style={styles.webview}
          ref={this.WEBVIEW_REF}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.WEBVIEW_REF.current.goBack()}>
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', color: '#FFFFFF'}}>Back Button</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  webview: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    padding: 20, 
    backgroundColor: '#2196f3', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
});
```

[image]